# Beamer miniframes: how to include section number alongside section name?

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I am using a Beamer theme (Singapore) that is using Miniframes for the header. This header will contain section names, but not their number.

## What I would like

I would like to include the section numbers alongside the section name.

It looks like this:

```
First section    Second section    Another section
o o o o          o o o o           o o o
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
1 First section    2 Second section    3 Another section
o o o o            o o o o             o o o
```

## What I tried

I tried looking how it is done (in `beamerouterthememiniframes.sty`), and this seems to be how the header is defined in Miniframes :

```latex
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

If I understand well, it is the `\insertnavigation` tag that does the job of printing section names. I am stuck here, since I can’t just add section numbers (with `\thesection` I think).

## Question

How do I include section numbers with the section name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the `\sectionentry` to include the number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\makeatletter
\def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
  \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
  \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
  \beamer@ypos@offset=0\relax%
  \ifnum#5=\c@part%
  \beamer@section@set@min@width%
  \box\beamer@sectionbox\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill%
  \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=
  \hbox{\def\insertsectionhead{#1~#2}%
    \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}%
    \def\insertpartheadnumber{#5}%
    {%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
      \ifnum\c@section=#1%
        \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}%
      \else%
        \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}%
      \fi}%
  }%
  \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
  \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
  \fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, blazing fast, accurate answer! Even in time for my next presentation this afternoon, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bastien Good luck with your presentation! :)

Comment: Thanks! ❤ (It went well)

Comment: @Bastien Happy to hear!